# How to set vim.keymap.set to run clang-format

Tags: clang, neovim, clang-format

So I've installed the clang-format on my ubuntu machine and I want to make a keymap that everytime I  to format my current working file. I had this for other languages, using `null-ls` and `mason-lspconfig`:

```
vim.keymap.set('n', '<Esc>', ':Format<CR>', { noremap = true, silent = true })

vim.keymap.set('i', '<Esc>', '<Esc>:w<CR>:Format<CR>', { noremap = true, silent = true })
```

This works with clang LSP, but is not formatting the way I want, that's why I want to use clang-format ( witch shows in :Mason but idk how to set it up from there ). So I wanted to remap the previous keymaps using this:

```
if check_cpp(curr_file) then

local command = string.format('clang-format --style=file -i %s', vim.fn.shellescape(curr_file))

vim.fn.system(command)

end
```

How should I do it?